# Highcharts: Add plotlines to legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to add plotline to legend. Here is my example http://jsfiddle.net/y6yvqtdv/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        // one day
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
        plotLines: [{ // mark the weekend
            color: 'green',
            width: 3,
            value: 250,
            dashStyle: 'dash'
        }]
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
    }]
});
```

How can I add green dashed line to the existing graphs legend?

Comment: Better is using extra serie, with defined two points (first and last x).

Comment: @SebastianBochan How to get the last point?

Comment: set data as external array, and then refer to data[len-1]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and Solved it by

> 1) Defining the min and max values for the x Axis 
>   2) Plotting a new series with values less than min and greater than max
>   3) Give it a color and remove the labels

I tried changing your fiddle but was not able to demonstrate , but it has worked for me. Let me know if it worked for you or if you need more information